# Google VM broken after I applied recommended resize

Tags: virtual-machine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a virtual machine on google's cloud platform which I had been running a website with no problems for a few months. Today, I followed the recommendations (as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/apply-machine-type-recommendations-for-instances?_ga=2.126347725.-1946186000.1651319368)) to downsize my machine type to one of lower memory (3GB) as the current one (8GB) was being underutilised.

After I received a notification in the Google Cloud Platform Console that the resize was complete, I tried to access the website but received a 502 Bad Gateway error from NGINX (which I was using to serve the website). I then tried to SSH to the VM instance via the console, but got these errors (same as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63566055/cannot-ssh-into-the-gcp-vm-instances-that-used-to-work)):

```
Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed
Code: 4010
Reason: destination read failed
You may be able to connect without using the Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy.
```

So I retried with Cloud Identity-Award Proxy disabled. But then it reads:

```
Connection Failed
An error occurred while communicating with the SSH server. Check the server and the network configuration.
```

I can confirm that I have already settled any firewall settings for port 22 as I've been using this VM for a while now.

I also tried resetting the VM instance but that didn't do anything.

I further tried to connect to the VM instance via the Google Cloud Shell, and for some reason that worked. However, when I tried to run `sudo systemctl start nginx` or any other `systemctl` command, I get this error:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

I've never seen this message before. It's quite frustrating that clicking one apply resize button can break my VM since it's an action recommended by the console. Did I do something wrong? Do I have to create a new instance from an old snapshot?

(Machine type is e2-custom-2-3072, Disk Image/OS is Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye))

Comment: If I were to guess the VM is in recovery mode.

Comment: Do you have any of these options enabled: https://cloud.google.com/compute/shielded-vm/docs/shielded-vm

Comment: @JohnHanley i’ve never used anything related to shielded VM, so I wouldn’t think so, unless it’s a default option

Comment: Did you go to the Console GUI and check? What do the Cloud Logging show for your VM? Login using the serial console and check the boot logs. What errors show?